# Time-Invariant (non)autonomous Systems

Tags: linear-systems, control-systems, dynamic-system

Regarding potential distinctions between autonomous, non-autonomous, time-invariant and time-varying systems, I have found out opinions supporting that:

1. autonomous systems are time-invariant and non-autonomous are time-varying,
   (A treatise on stability of autonomous and non-autonomous systems, R. Adhikari - ‎2013)
2. linear systems can be time varying or invariant, nonlinear systems can be autonomous or non-autonomous
   [Book](https://books.google.de/books?id=lQSiDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)
3. systems can be simultaneously characterised as any combination among the above, which indicates that they cannot be the same thing.
   (Adversary Control Tactics for Cyberphysical Systems, Kontouras, 2020 - non-autonomous linear time invariant)
   (Realization and identiﬁcation of autonomous linear periodically time-varying systems, Markovsky et al.-autonomous linear time varying)

The example is about LTI but it would be the same for LTV.

This system:
[image: open-loop]

$\ddot{y}-b\dot{y}-ay=u(t)$

$y=x_{1}$,
$\dot{x_{1}}=x_{2}$,
$\dot{x_{2}}=ax_{1}+bx_{2}+u(t)$

$\dot{\vec{x}}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
 a&b 
\end{bmatrix}\vec{x}+\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}u(t)$

, is time-invariant since $A$, $B$ matrices are not time-dependent, and since there is a time-dependent input $u(t)$, it should additionally be non-autonomous.

If we feed the output $y$ back, the input $u(t)$, will now become a function of state variables. In this sense, the system should be autonomous.

[image: closed-loop]

$\dot{\vec{x}}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
 a&b 
\end{bmatrix}\vec{x}+\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}u(t)$

$y=x_{1}$

$u(t)=-ky$

Do the previous make sense?
Is it that open-loop control systems are in principle non-autonomous, while closed-loop ones are autonomous, in the absence of additional time-dependent disturbances?